# How can I build this Spinning Bird Kick move?

Tags: powers, mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-2e

I was trying to formulate the Spinning Bird Kick move from Chun-Li using 2nd edition:

[image: Chun-Li from Street Fighter, performing a spinning kick where she hovers upside-down while her legs rotate like helicopter blades before landing on her feet]

But I'm not sure how to cover the ability to move and attack at the same time. How can I build this move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonically, there is no mechanical way to build a power like that. Movement and attack are separate. However, there are a few approaches. For non-Area approaches, Autofire is popular for attacks like this, to model possibly hitting several times.

### Don't require movement, but allow it as flavor and/or use a Complication for needing clearance

This is the simplest solution. Just build the attack and the player can describe some of their Move action as moving in the kick before striking. The Complication models that she might not be able to pull it off on confined spaces, or turn corners. You might also Move-By Action to let her move, kick a single target, then move again.

### Add a Drawback or Flaw requiring movement

If she can't just jump up and kick in place, a Drawback models that she has to use either her Move action or free 5 foot step. If she always has to use her entire Move action over the attack and must basically do a straight line, that sounds like a good Flaw.

### Use Area or Autofire to hit multiple spaces

Autofire can be paired with the above approach and attack multiple targets with a cumulative penalty. Alternately Area (Line) works for the linear approach. Area (Trail) is more tricky mechanically because it requires you to move through the space you're affecting. Either way, you may need to buy the Reduced Area Feat.